# Forward / backward words in the VSCode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

What `commandID`'s govern moving **forward** or **backward** a **word** in the VSCode terminal? (say running Zsh)

#### Background

I know that these commands are bound `Option + Right` and `Option + Left` respectively since I can try that in the terminal and the cursort moves forward and backward one word accordingly.

When I search for those keybindings in the Keyboard Shortcuts menu, I find the following commandIDs tied to them:

- `cursorWordStart` (Left or Right)
- `cusorWordAccessibility` (Left or Right)

**However** I'm observing here something odd. If I bind both commands to `Command+F` and `Command + B` respectively (with **no** `when` clause), I'm **not** able to use these keybindings to move forward/backward a word in the terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no expert in this area but I assume that the <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> keybinding is being handled by your shell – vscode has nothing to do with that.  So you won’t find a command that vscode is using to skip forward or backward in the terminal.

But you can implement one yourself by [sending the control codes to the shell](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding). For that, modify your keybinding settings (keybindings.json). You can open it with the command palette (accessible with <kbd>⌘</kbd> +  <kbd>⇧</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd>), searching for “Open Keyboard Shortcuts **(JSON)**”. Then make an addition like:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+b",          // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
      "text": "\u001b[;5D"
  },
  "when": "terminalFocus && !terminalTextSelected"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+f",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
      "text": "\u001b[;5C"
  },
  "when": "terminalFocus && !terminalTextSelected"
},
```

Swap `cmd` for `ctrl` depending on your OS. You didn’t specify what shell you’re using but it works on Git Bash and CMD.exe on Windows – all I can test on here.

`\u001b[` is the control sequence introducer, so that what follows is interpreted as a control sequence and not as literal characters.

The `5D` is the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>.  The `5` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.  The `D` is cursor back. You can find further bindings in the [section “PC-Style Function Keys” of the `ctlseqs` documentation](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys).  I believe the `;` is necessary to indicate that the following is a control character, in this case `5` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and not the digit 5.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I just updated the OP to indicate it's Zsh. QQ: Where did you get the text arguments for those commands? (where can I look them up?). Also, if VSCode isn't doing it directly, what's `cursorWordStart[Left|Right` and `cusorWordAccessibility[Left|Right]` for? In any case, I'm trying this now

Comment: Excellent, I added a couple of links to documentation in the answer.   I use the `sendSequence` command for quickly changing my terminal directory to the current file's directory and re-running the last shell command from anywhere alot.

Comment: Thanks - This is indeed an extremely useful feature, i.e. being able to send commands to the terminal (somewhat related to what one could do with `tasks.json`). I now wonder - is there a way to send commands or a sequence to a **specific** terminal using this approach? (e.g. either a new terminal, or one just created for that purpose, or an existing one). I can ask that in a sep. question though.

Comment: I don't believe so - it only takes the `text` argument so can only target the active terminal.  Plus, this particular keybinding has a `terminalFocus` when clause since `ctrl+B/F` have other uses in the editor.  But even my changeTerminalDirectory only targets the "active" terminal with multiple open.

Comment: You could make a macro which creates a new terminal, focusses it, and then sendSequences to that terminal if that is a process you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks! by a macro, do you mean a task in `tasks.json` or something else? (or do you mean e.g. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros)

Comment: I meant a macro in the sense of some macro extensions that allow chaining of commands like multi-command and others.

Comment: Nice - Thanks! and how did you figure out that `\u001b[1;5D` was **exactly** the right string? (I searched for **forward** and **backward** words in the links you sent without luck..)

Comment: I added a little about the control sequence - they don't all work for me BTW.  I removed the `1` from this sequence it is unnecessary (and probably the default).

Comment: Mark - Wondering if you have handy (or know) the one for *deleting words* from the terminal. Following what you said, I know it should start with `\u001b[` but I could not find the instruction to delete words in the [ordered list](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_) of you shared above

Comment: I got it. For this specifically, control sequences won't work (see [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554269/xterm-control-sequences-for-backward-forward-word-deletion) of mine), but I found that I can use `workbench.action.terminal.deleteWordRight`, so all set! :)

Comment: Omitting the 1 between [ and ; from `\u001b[1;5D` broke the functionality for me on macos.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on macos and I needed to do this:

```
    {
        "key": "cmd+r",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": { "text": "\u0012" }, // reverse command search
        "when": "terminalFocus"
      },
      {
        "key": "cmd+c",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "\u0003" // send interrupt, cancel command
        },
        "when": "terminalFocus"
      },
      {
        "key": "cmd+left",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
            "text": "\u001b[1;5D" // cursor one word left
        },
        "when": "terminalFocus"
      },
      {
        "key": "cmd+right",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
            "text": "\u001b[1;5C" // cursor one word right
        },
        "when": "terminalFocus"
      },
```

hope it helps somebody

Comment: This worked for me in Ventura 13.5, thanks! I used "alt+b" to move a word backward/left with `Opt+b`, and "alt+f" to move a word forward/right with `Opt+f`.